# Reader cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: java

I could use a few pointers, new to Java.

I am using a function that returns a "Reader" type.  Documented here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html?is-external=true

Here are my lines of code:

```java
Reader test = null;

test = WWIO.openReader("http://google.com");
```

The second line is okay, but the first puts an error on "Reader" saying

```
Reader cannot be resolved to a type
```

Why is that?  I have

```
import java.lang.Object;
```

Which I don't even think is necessary?  Why doesn't the compiler understand the type?

Comment: `import java.lang.Object;` is completely pointless.

Comment: If you want to use `Reader`, then that is what you should be importing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse, pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> may help **a lot** ;)

Since `java.io.Reader` is under the package `java.io`, you need to import that package.

```
import java.io.Reader;
```

or

```
import java.io.*;
```

Alternatively, you can qualify it directly in the code:

```
java.io.Reader test = null;
```

(that is useful when you need to use two different classes with the same name)

Note that `java.lang` package is automatically available, so there is no need to import it.

Comment: @ZouZou Usually it asks you which import you want if there are more than one possible.

Comment: @arshajii WOOPS, you're absolutely right !

Answer (score 7):

While

```
 import java.lang.Object;
```

really is not necessary, you need to include

```
 import java.io.Reader;
```

Answer (score 3):

Import the reader using

```
import java.io.*;
```

The compiler excludes unused imports, so using the asterisk won't have any negative effect.

More direct is obviously

`import java.io.Reader;`

Comment: As far as I know this doesn't affect the program and it's more a matter of preference. I for one prefer to use it as it avoids lines of code which will result in me having to scroll, and it immediatly negates the need to import from the same package twice. Edit: this was in response to someone saying it's better to directly import instead.

Answer (score 3):

You should have

```
import java.io.Reader;
```

Importing `java.lang.Object` is completely unnecessary. Actually, importing every class from the `java.lang.*` package is unnecessary, since they're imported by default.